# How to find coordinates of every point of vector created from on point to another

Tags: algorithm, vector, geometry, console-application, rasterizing

I have 2 points, for example `A(1, 30)`, `B(20, 10)`. I should draw in console the vector with nearest path of `*`. I should get every point of path, how can I do this?

Comment: Look at the Bressenham Algorithm for rasterizing a line segment.

Answer (score 0):

There may be various solutions for it. One solution is to iterate (for example using two `for` loops) over all points between `A` and `B`  and check whether the line passes through each point.

And you need a criterion to decide whether the line segment `AB` passes through a specific point `P(x,y)`. For example you can measure the Euclidian distance of point `P` to line `AB`. Then the point lies on the line if the distance is smaller than a specific value, say 0.5.

Another criterion to decide whether `P` lies on `AB` is to check whether the line `AB` passes through a 1x1 square centered at `P(x,y)`. The four corners of this square are `P1(x-0.5,y-0.5)`, `P2(x-0.5,y+0.5)`, `P3(x+0.5,y-0.5)` and `P4(x+0.5,y+0.5)`. To figure out whether the line passes through this square, you can evaluate these four corners and determine whether all lie on the same side of the line. If so, the line does not cross the square and otherwise it crosses the square.

Using each criterion, you will obtain a set of points that are assumed to lie on the line segment.

Comment: It is not reliable way. Look at the comment of Mark Lavin.
.